# Gradlew unable to retrieve passwords from files

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I'm using Gradle to (try to) build my apk. This is the relevant part of my build.gradle file:

```
    signingConfigs {
        release {
            storeFile new File("cmp.keystore")
//            storePassword(new File("cmpstorage.pwd").text)
            storePassword "123456"
            keyAlias("cmp_alias")
//            keyPassword(new File("cmpkey.pwd").text)
            keyPassword "123456"
        }
    }
```

Basically, if I try to put the passwords in text files and tell Gradle to retrieve them, it fails ("Keystore was tampered with or password is incorrect"), but having them typed in the file works perfectly. However, this is a huge annoyance, mainly for VCS.

For my other apps the method of storing the passwords in files has always worked, so to be honest I have no clue on what could be going wrong.

Comment: The file contents have a trailing carriage return?

Comment: Thought about it so I echoed the password through cmd instead of writing it through an editor, but it didn't work either.

Comment: You could put some debugging print statements in the build file to show what it's actually reading from the file and compare it to the hardcoded values.

Comment: By debugging in this way I've found that it was actually a trailing space problem (from now on I guess I know that `echo` also prints a trailing space). Thanks.